# MongoDB with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I want to develop Rails application. Before it, I used PostgreSQL and MySQL database with my rails application. But now I want to use MongoDB with my Rails application. What are the benefits of using MongoDB in comparison to other database?

Comment: Try and you'll find out.

Comment: -1 What kind of application you want to develop? Why do you want to use MongoDB?

Comment: I want to develop an application which will be able to store large data records. I listen about document-oriented database, but don't know briefly about it. So, I need some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great intro  MonogoDB:

http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've used MongoDB with a project before for the following reasons:

**schema-less**

- It will allow more flexibility for your database, no strict rules for what attributes your records can contain.

**fire and forget**

- It can allow you to do faster inserts to the database.

**easy scaling**

- It supports sharding to distribute the load to more systems, though I never got to this point for my app.

One thing I've found not so good is doing aggregation tasks. Simple aggregation tasks usually requires you to do a map reduce. While map reduce is not really bad, it's not that fast either and may increase complexity for your application.

To know more about the pros and cons, you can check out their site:

http://www.mongodb.org/